# Сортировка серии при извлечении из датафрэйма

Tags: python, pandas

делаю:

```
s = dataframe[column_name]
```

в результате получаю в s серию отсортированную по значению.
почему происходит сортировка, как ее избежать ?

```
def fit_transform(self, dataframe):
    for name in dataframe.columns:
        ranges = self.get_ranges(dataframe[name].values)
        test=dataframe[name]
        for i in range(len(test)):
            print(test[i])
        dataframe[name] = dataframe[name].apply(lambda x: self.range_value(ranges, x))
    return dataframe
```

в test получаю:

```
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-0.9
-0.9
-0.9
-0.9
-0.9
-0.9
```

это сортированые значения. (все копировать не стал, много очень)

Comment: чего-то вы недоговариваете. В этом случае вы получаете данные ровно в таком виде как они распологоаются в данном столбце в DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае вы получите данные ровно в таком виде как они распологаются в данном столбце в `DataFrame` (индекс у `Series` будет такой-же как у `DataFrame`).

Пример:

```
In [82]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [83]: df
Out[83]:
   a  b  c
0  5  7  7
1  1  8  7
2  8  7  9
3  4  0  3
4  7  5  0

In [84]: s = df['c']

In [85]: s
Out[85]:
0    7
1    7
2    9
3    3
4    0
Name: c, dtype: int32
```

Comment: обновил вопрос, написал более подробно.

Comment: @PetrStukalov, что делают `get_ranges()` и `range_value()`?

Comment: считают рейтинги. это к делу не относится. т.к. они не вносят изменений в dataframe.

Comment: @PetrStukalov, как это не относится??? Вы заменяете значения в `dataframe[name]` на значения, которые вернула `self.range_value(ranges, x)`

Comment: а какая разница ? на печать я вывожу через индекс, который в серии.

Comment: я его заменяю после полученяи серии test и ее вывода.

Comment: @PetrStukalov, вы выводите на печать по __отсортированным__ значениям индекса - если в исходном DF индекс не отсортирован - вы меняете порядок

Comment: Зачем вам цикл для вывода `test` на печать, напишите просто `print(test)`

Comment: ну правильно, беда только в том что индекс серии test не совпадает с индексом dataframe. в серии индекс почему то стал по возрастанию значения.

Comment: на а что вы хотели? `range(len(test))` - возвращает __отсортированные__ значения

Comment: написал print(test). ничего не изменилась сортировка идет по значению а не по индексу.

Comment: @PetrStukalov, "не верю!" (с) Станиславский. добавьте следующей или предыдущей строкой `print(dataframe[name])`

Comment: @PetrStukalov, вывод совпадает?

Comment: нашел проблему. индексы меняются после строки ranges = self.get_ranges(dataframe[name].values). а там есть такая строчка list.sort(). я думал dataframe.values возвращвет копию данных, а он возвращает ссылку на сами данные используемые в dataframe. я их сортирую, и соответственно меняется порядок в серии датафрэйма.

Comment: @PetrStukalov, лучше использовать `dataframe[name].sort_values()` или `np.sort(np_array)`